# How to check if a binary number contains digits different from 0 and 1 in c?

Tags: c

I want to write a function that prompts the user to input bin_num binary sequence of 0-s and 1-s and
outputs the following.

A) Decimal representation of bin_num

B) Hexadecimal representation of bin_num (base 16)

If the input is invalid (that is, if bin_num contains digits different from 0 and 1), the user should
receive an error message (detailed below).

> Example of the program run:
>
> ```
> Please enter binary number input: 112011
>
> invalid input, please try again.
>
> Please enter binary number input: 110011
>
> 110011 to decimal is: 51
>
> 110011 to hexadecimal is: 0x33
> ```

In order to solve the problem correctly, I will not be able to read the binary numbers as
integers, since it might cause an overflow.
On the other hand, the answer (in decimal) will always fit the standard integer size.

**My question is How to check if the binary number contains digits different from 0 and 1?**

> This is my code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define ENTERING_QUESTION "Please choose a question by entering 1-5 (enter 0 to exit):" 


#define MAX_SIZE_INPUT 31
#define QUESTION1_INPUT_MESSAGE "Please enter binary number input:"
#define QUESTION1_OUTPUT_MESSAGE_DECIMAL "to decimal is:"
#define QUESTION1_OUTPUT_MESSAGE_HEXADECIMAL "to hexadecimal is:"
#define QUESTION1_ERROR_MESSAGE "invalid input, please try again."
void bin2hexanddec(char *bin_str)
{
    char *ptr;
    long long input_num= strtol(bin_str, &ptr, 10);
    int dec = 0, i = 0, rem;
    
    while (input_num != 0) {
        rem = input_num % 10;
        input_num /= 10;
        dec += rem * pow(2, i);
        ++i;
    }
    printf("%lld " QUESTION1_OUTPUT_MESSAGE_DECIMAL " %d\n", input_num, dec);
    printf("%lld " QUESTION1_OUTPUT_MESSAGE_DECIMAL " %X\n", input_num, dec);

    return;

}

.
.
.
int main()
{

    char bin_str[MAX_SIZE_INPUT
    .
    .
    .
    printf(ENTERING_QUESTION"\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
        if (choice == 1) {
            printf(QUESTION1_INPUT_MESSAGE"\n");
            scanf("%s", bin_str);
            bin2hexanddec(bin_str);
        }
    .
    .
    .


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty dang sure no binary number contains other digits than 0 or 1 :) So what are you actually asking here, how to sanitize user input strings?

Comment: You could just write a check function which would take the user input, see if only `0` and `1`  are present and give error accordingly

Comment: I get the binary number from the user and I need to check the correctness of the input. @Lundin

Comment: @Abhishek I need to write these just in the same function no in a separate function, or in the main function.

Comment: `scanf("%s", bin_str);` you input a string. Now: check if this string contains other characters than '0' and '1'. Good luck!

Comment: @wildplasser how can I write it ?

Comment: Use an editor to write it.

Comment: Well, as it happens `strtol` has built-in error checking. You can use that, simply make the base parameter variable.

Comment: You can check if there are any characters other than `'0'` and `'1'` in a string with [`strspn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strspn-wcsspn-mbsspn-mbsspn-l?view=vs-2019).

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen wow!! I didn't knew that

Comment: @Lundin I didn't understand what are exactly mean can you give me an example

Answer (score 0):

it is very simple.

```
int isbinary(const char *str)  //zero if OK non zero if not OK
{
    while(*str && (*str == '0' || *str == '1')) str++;
    return *str;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n",isbinary("101100001011") ? "NOT OK" : "OK");
    printf("%s\n",isbinary("101100e01011") ? "NOT OK" : "OK");
}
```

if you want non zero to be OK just change `return *str;` to `return !*str;`

https://godbolt.org/z/6nq-TC

your conversion algorithm does not make too much sense.

```
unsigned long long convert(const char *str)
{
    unsigned long long result = 0;

    while(*str)
    {
        result <<= 1;
        result += *str++ == '1';
    }
    return result;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/_KQR4f